# What is the legal implications of failure to pay Ultra Low Emission Zone charges?

Tags: england-and-wales, environmental

Bob has driven through the [Ultra Low Emission Zone](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/driving/ultra-low-emission-zone) but not paid to requisite fee. What are the legal consequences of this for Bob?

Answer (score 6):

> We may issue a Penalty Charge Notice (PCN) if you drive within the Ultra Low Emission Zone (ULEZ) in a vehicle that does not meet the emissions standards and you do not pay the correct daily charge.

https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/driving/ultra-low-emission-zone/penalty-charges-for-ulez

Car £180, or £90 if paid within 14 days.

---

In comments the questioner says that the question is about ignoring the ULEZ *and* ignoring any penalties subsequent to that.

From the page above:

> To understand how a PCN may progress, see our [enforcement process page](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/driving/ultra-low-emission-zone/enforcement-process).

See also the [London Tribunals enforcemennt page](https://www.londontribunals.gov.uk/ruc/understanding-enforcement-process).

If you receive a PCN you have 28 days to pay or write to TfL to challenge it. If you pay within 28 days the amount you have to pay is half the original amount.

If you do neither then the charge is increased by 50% and "a charge certificate will be sent to the registered keeper of the vehicle". Car was £180, now £270 (180+180/2). You have 14 days to pay.

If you do not pay within 14 days then TfL "may apply to register it as an unpaid debt at the Traffic Enforcement Centre which incurs a debt registration fee for each PCN."

Then an [Order for Recovery](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/order-for-recovery-of-unpaid-penalty-charge-form-te3) is sent to the registered keeper of the vehicle. This is not a County Court Judgment and will not affect your credit rating. The penalty is increased by the debt registration fee (£8).

You have 21 days to pay that. After that, TfL asks for a 'warrant of execution', which is passed to a 'civil enforcement agent' (aka bailiff).

The enforcement agent will write to you and charge fees for every letter, visit and action taken.

Ultimately the enforcement agents will attempt to remove your property to sell it to recover the total outstanding debt.

Comment: The thing is, the entire point is it is about refusal to pay as some totally object in principle to the sceme. So suppose that one refuses to pay the £90 and then £180. What can come of it then?

Comment: I can't say what happens in this case, but if you don't pay for your train ticket and get caught, you first get a letter to please pay for a ticket at a higher price, then a letter to please pay the ticket and a fine, then a letter to please pay the ticket and a higher fine or go to court, then a letter to go to court where you will typically get a £600 fine, for say a £10 train ticket. The next step would be bailiffs and possibly they go to your employer and ask them to pay your debt out of your salary. You _will_ lose if you have any property and/or a job.

Comment: "The thing is, the entire point is it is about refusal to pay” - do you think the wording of your question makes your point clear?

Comment: @Seekinganswers Objection to a law does not remedy breaking it. Not paying fines will follow the normal process of unpaid fines,. First they accumulate with late fees, then they will result in the court sending a bailiff to confiscate valuables of appropriate value to pay for fines.

Comment: @Lag sorry, perhaps not though also arguably somewhat through the tag “civil disobedience” that was included.

Comment: @trish of course the law doesn’t care if you object to part of it. But, the question is if you persistently fail to pay the escalated penalties.

Comment: No, the question asks about one incident,  as it is posed. Nothing indicates a pattern or constant nonpayment.

Comment: "Civil disobedience" is not an excuse. I actually have been told that if you claim "civil disobedience" then you ought to accept the consequences and not fight them, because the point of civil disobedience is to demonstrate that there are laws that shouldn't be in place.

Comment: @Seekinganswers Doesn't "Ultimately the enforcement agents will attempt to remove your property to sell it to recover the total outstanding debt." answer your question?

Comment: @ohwilleke, No because bailiffs in the UK are often unsuccessful at recovering anything. The question is more of any kind of enduring consequence such as criminal records or credit reference score etc.